# Disallow characters in search field? Magento 1.8.1.0

Tags: magento-1.8

Is it possible to disallow certain characters in the search bar in Magento 1.8.1.0?

We are getting a few searches of what looks like a Mysql attack using characters like "$().// etc

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like below.
Go to your **form.mini.phtml** file in

```
app/design/frontend/YOUR_PACKAGE/YOUR_THEME/template/catalogsearch/
```

Add below javasctipt function in your file.

```
function validate() {
    var element = document.getElementById('search');
    element.value = element.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9@]+/, '');
};
```

Now add `onkeyup="validate();"` in your textbox like below.

```
<input onkeyup="validate();" id="search" type="text" 
name="<?php echo $catalogSearchHelper->getQueryParamName() ?>" 
value="<?php echo $catalogSearchHelper->getEscapedQueryText() ?>" 
class="input-text" 
maxlength="<?php echo $catalogSearchHelper->getMaxQueryLength();?>" />
```

Comment: Thanks, I got it to work on development site.. I changed "var element = document.getElementById('input-field');" to "var element = document.getElementById('search');"  Is this still correct?

Comment: @CallamWarner-Billington, Thanks. It was a typo mistake. I have updated the code.

Comment: Didn't work, the search terms are still coming through? http://i.cubeupload.com/Ub8OrV.png

Comment: Can you check by enabling template path hints if the file which you edited is the correct file? Also have you refreshed your cache?

Comment: I've just flushed the cache and the file i edited is located: app\design\frontend\default\ma_kidstore\template\catalogsearch - I've cleared all search terms so will update if they come through again.

Comment: @CallamWarner-Billington Can you please check in your search textbox if you can add special characters in it by typing? Because the code will prevent any special character to be typed in search box.

Comment: That's the thing, it does work. As soon as I enter any special sign like £/() etc, it gets stripped automatically. An update to my post earlier, it doesn't appear to be working still as I'm getting the search results come through. I'm not sure how the bots are entering the information because copy and paste doesn't work for me which surely is the method they use? :\